# Jackson JSON mapping of Strings

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I used POJO's as @RequestBody parameters and they worked fine. But now I try something like this `public void func(@RequestBody String s)` and cant pass the value to String s. When I used POJO's I writes {"attribute" : "value"} in request and the question is what I should write in POSTMAN to pass the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send only string value then it is better idea to use @RequestParam and in postman client you can send key value parameter.

```
public String method(@RequestParam("key") String value){

}
```